# Issues with sp_HelpText stripping out dbo schema in response

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

When I call the following

`EXEC sp_HelpText 'dbo.NameOfTrigger'`

I get the following returned

`CREATE TRIGGER NameOfTrigger ON  [dbo].[NameOfTable] FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE`

However when I call the same type of call but on another schema

`EXEC sp_HelpText 'AnotherSchema.NameOfTrigger'`

I get the result

`CREATE TRIGGER [AnotherSchema].[NameOfTrigger] ON [AnotherSchema].[NameOfTable]`

Is there a way of forcing SQL Server (MSSQL 2014) to include the [dbo] added to the NameOfTrigger e.g.

`CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[NameOfTrigger] ON  [dbo].[NameOfTable] FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE`

We need this for some code in Entity Framework to handle table renames in a custom migration SQL generations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying some things in my dev environment to see if I could replicate your issue.  It seems your trigger was originally created without specifying the dbo schema in the CREATE TRIGGER statement.

This CREATE TRIGGER statement results in the dbo schema being displayed in the sp_helptext results:

`CREATE TRIGGER dbo.NameOfTrigger ON ...`

However, this one doesn't:

`CREATE TRIGGER NameOfTrigger ON ...`

(The second statement still defaults the schema to dbo.)

Example:

[image: sp_helptext example]

So I would say try dropping and recreating your trigger, but this time use the dbo schema in the CREATE TRIGGER statement.  Then you should be able to feed to EF.

Chalk another one up to "always specify the schema"...

Comment: Thanks, after doing some more investigations I think that this is what happened and that another member of the team broke with the design document and did not specify the schema when making bulk changes to these triggers, in the real version there are almost 300 of them.  Thanks for your help.